# How to get `git commit --verbose` output via `git diff`?

Tags: git

The goal I'm after is to call, for example, `git diff --verbose` (error: invalid option) to get the same output that you get when calling `git commit --verbose`:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   README.md
#
# Untracked files:
#   .gitignore
#
# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------
# Do not touch the line above.
# Everything below will be removed.
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 267d5e2..b5f70de 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@

-# Sandbox
+# SANDBOX

+Some new text
```

I found `git diff --patch-with-stat` which is *so close* but the output isn't quite as friendly, and it does not show untracked files, which I need.

```
 README.md | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 267d5e2..b5f70de 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@

-# Sandbox
+# SANDBOX

+Some new text
```

Where is `git diff --verbose`? Is there some way to get the same output as `git commit --verbose` through another command?

Answer (score 1):

`git diff --patch --stat` remains the best option, but could benefit from one additional command:

```
git ls-files -o
```

With `-o`, the [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) will show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output.

---

Warning, `git diff --verbose` will no longer just output only `error: invalid option: --verbose`.

"[`git diff --no-such-option`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f137bd4358bba70cede3e3198cbd50fd656b70a9/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> and other corner cases around the exit status of the diff command has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit 5cc6b2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cc6b2d70bc55ab75913ee93d9ac96ad875fbb29), [commit c0049ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0049ca0d7d4afb2d71ac76eba45d693facfc1d3), [commit 25bd3ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25bd3acd048152dcf2de5f446d2bd21b5fb42b09), [commit 3755077](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3755077b506356017d942dbcc2ffe9cb17ecc606), [commit 5ad6e2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ad6e2b495dfb7264fc94dc548af9c0a10901683), [commit f126f6e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f126f6ec221ec9f8aac3f1aebf855bbc46e9b796) (21 Aug 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 976b97e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/976b97e3fd95d5daa38ed453349f5a92157a1db2) (21 Aug 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f137bd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f137bd4358bba70cede3e3198cbd50fd656b70a9), 01 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ad6e2b495dfb7264fc94dc548af9c0a10901683): show usage for unknown `builtin_diff_files()` options
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Romain Chossart</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The [`git-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5ad6e2b495dfb7264fc94dc548af9c0a10901683/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> command has many modes (comparing worktree to index, index to HEAD, individual blobs, etc).
> As a result, it dispatches to many helper functions and cannot completely parse its options until we're in those helper functions.
>
> Most of them, when seeing an unknown option, exit immediately by calling `usage()`.
> But `builtin_diff_files()`, which is the default if no revision or blob arguments are given, instead prints an `error()` and returns -1.
>
> One obvious shortcoming here is that the user doesn't get to see the usual usage message.
> But there's a much more important bug: the -1 return is fed to `diff_result_code()`, which is not ready to handle it.
> By default, it passes the code along as an exit code.
> We try to avoid negative exit codes because they get converted to unsigned values, but it should at least consistently show up as non-zero (i.e., a failure).
>
> But much worse is that when `--exit-code` is in effect, `diff_result_code()` will *ignore* the status passed in by the caller, and instead only report on whether the diff found changes.
> It didn't, of course, because we never ran the diff, and the program unexpectedly exits with success!
>
> We can fix this bug by just calling `usage()`, like the other helpers do.
> Another option would of course be to teach `diff_result_code()` to handle this value.
> But as we'll see in the next few patches, it can be cleaned up even further.
> Let's just fix this bug directly to start with.